# Brightness Controls not working on HP Victus 15

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, laptop, brightness

I have a HP Victus 15 Laptop with Ryzen 7 5800H and RTX 3050. I have tried to install multiple distros (Ubuntu 22.04LTS, Pop_OS 22.04LTS, Fedora 38, currently on Ubuntu 23.04) on this laptop to dual boot with Windows, but all of them have the same problem. The brightness controls are inverted for whichever distro I have installed. Also, the brightness to begin with was lower than Windows as well.

I fixed the low brightness problem by changing the grub file as such:

[image: My Current Grub File]

Now, the brightness is set to the max, while the brightness keys and slider have been rendered ineffective.
How to fix this problem? This would be of great help as my eyes are currently burning.